# How can I create an OpenCV sharpening matrix in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, opencv, matrix, kernel

I am trying to sharpen an image using a sharpening convolution kernel like below:

```
[[0,-1,0], [-1,5,-1], [0,-1,0]];
```

Is it possible to define arbitrary matrices like this?

I can do this simply in OpenCV for python by declaring a numpy array like above, but in JavaScript (OpenCV.js) it seems there is no way to do this without using the Mat method and some combination of other methods.

I have tried like this:

```
let kdata = [[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]];
let M = new cv.Mat(kdata);
```

and by following the example here:

https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d6a/tutorial_js_filtering.html

But I can't find anything that allows me to create arbitrary matrices where I have control over each element in the matrix, only methods like eye() or ones() that fill the matrix with some pre-specified values.

Any help in creating arbitrary matrices that can be used with the `filter2d` method would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just spent the whole day trying to find the solution for this.

```
let kdata = [-1,-1,-1,-1,9,-1,-1,-1,-1] ;
let M = cv.matFromArray(3,3, cv.CV_32FC1,kdata);
```

I know this is a very old question but I hope this awnser is helpfull if anyone comes across this in the future.